# How to get id of removed element in jQuery auto complete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

I am using kendoUI auto complete. To display each record in the box format with "x" mark I have implemented like

```
$("#roleAuto").kendoAutoComplete({
                       dataSource: roledata,
                       filter: "startswith",
                       placeholder: "Select Role...",
                       select: function (e, ui) {
                           alert("hi");
                           $(".roleSelection:checked").each(function () {
                               var role = $(this).attr("data-name"),
                                     var  span = $("<span>").text(role),
                                        a = $("<a>").addClass("remove").attr({
                                        title: "Remove " + role
                                        }).text("x").appendTo(span);
                               alert(role);
                               span.insertBefore("#roleAuto");
                                $("#Roles").click(function () {
                                 $("#roleAuto").focus();
                                 });
             $(".remove", document.getElementById("Roles")).live("click", function () {
                     $(this).parent().remove();
                     if ($("#Roles span").length === 0) {
                     $("#roleAuto").css("top", 0);
                           }
                       });
                   });
```

I am able to display each record in the box with "x" symbol. If I click on the "x" mark I am able to remove the record, I want that removed item ID value. How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method for the autocomplete (and many of the other data-bound widgets):

kendo.ui.widget.dataItem(index);

And a method on the event called:

event.item.index();

Documentation for the AutoComplete-Methods: [AutoComplete Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/autocomplete#methods)

So, as your first line in the select function, you could write:

```
var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
```

Your live-method for the click-event would then look like the following:

```
$(".remove", document.getElementById("Roles")).live("click", function () {
    alert(dataItem.Id); //Or in whichever property your Id is stored.
    $(this).parent().remove();
    if ($("#Roles span").length === 0) {
        $("#roleAuto").css("top", 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: my live-method for the click-event is not working,If I put alert message also it is not coming.In the select function i am able to get the id value using dataItem.but I am not able to get the removed element id

Comment: What do you  mean with element id, isn't it the databound element id?